# How to make UITableView scrollview bounce the parent view when reached the end?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to that of the iPhone's music app's now playing feature, when it is scrolled to the top, the tableview seems to bounce the entire view rather than just its content. Anyone know how is this achieved?

[image]

I have tried nesting my TableView in a UIScrollview, hoping when it reaches the top it will bounce scroll the parent UIScrollview, but it didn't seem to do that.

I have tried the UIScrollViewDelegate's viewDidScroll, detect when it bounces and use the contentOffSet on its parent view, but that produced unnatural looking results.

Comment: Can you share your actual result? Maybe I wouldn't nest UITableView into UIScrollview. Bounce is in UIScrollView (which UITableView have inside itself) system by default enabled. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619420-bounces

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/221-recreating-the-apple-music-now-playing-transition